# How do I profile using jprofiler on remote linux server while my GUI in on windows OS?

Tags: linux, agent, jprofiler

I am trying to profile my remote linux server using JProfiler. I am trying to seek for a line of code which I need maybe to implement it inside my startup.sh script of this app.

any help would be great!

Erez

Comment: On SO, you need to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local JProfiler GUI, invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

and follow the steps in the wizard.